# Flask post delete, URL restrictions

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Sample code:

```
@app.route('/delete-update/<int:post_id>')
@login_required
def delete_update(post_id):
    try:
        p = Post.query.filter(Post.id == post_id).delete()
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Post successfully deleted')
    except:
        db.session.rollback()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

I can delete a post using this route by a button click, But how to prevent deleting a post by requesting the URL

*localhost:5000/delete-update/1*

Comment: You seem to be missing the port. By default your app will run on `localhost:5000`.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to prevent this. One thing you can do is restrict deletion to just the user who created the post, or an administrator. That's what I've done with my blog.

Comment: Thanks @mechanical_meat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `methods` attribute after your route definition.

```
@app.route('/delete-update', methods=['POST'])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #do your stuff
```

You can also use any default http method like `PUT, DELETE, PATCH`.

Be aware that with that change, if you do a request with method `GET` to:

```
http://localhost:5000/delete-update/1
```

you will receive a `405`response with message `method not allowed`.
That's because our route does not handle `GET` anymore

Also doing that you should change the button handle to send a request to that route with method `POST`.